# How to fetch mysql data having brackets?

Tags: mysql, select, fetch

I want to fetch mysql data having round brackets e.g. ABCD(XYZ). When I run query

```
"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Column = 'ABCD(XYZ)'"
```

it returns an empty result. Please suggest a way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should work. Could you show your data? By the way, these things are called parentheses.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? Just because you don't have such a record, how does that mean it's impossible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` (`Column`) VALUES ('ABCD(XYZ)');

SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `Column` = 'ABCD(XYZ)'";
```

Maybe 'ABCD(XYZ)' is not exactly the value of your data (for example if you inserted some whitespaces before or after it.)
You can try it with a like to find that out:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `Column` LIKE '%ABCD(XYZ)%'";
```

Another possibility is that your value has been converted with htmlentities and you saved something like this:

```
'ABCD&40;XYZ&41;'
```

> &40;                Left parenthesis
>
> &41;                Right parenthesis